# How to remove near zero variance without employing the caret package?

Tags: r, r-caret

I am new to programming. But here is the piece of code that I have tried to remove the `nearZeroVar` function of the `caret` package from:

```
N <- 200 # number of points per class
D <- 2 # dimensionality
K <- 4 # number of classes
X <- data.frame() # data matrix (each row = single example)
y <- data.frame() # class labels

...(some lines are omitted)...

X <- as.matrix(X)
Y <- matrix(0, N * K, K)
for (i in 1:(N * K)) { Y[i, y[i,]] <- 1}

...(some lines are omitted)...

nzv <- nearZeroVar(train)
nzv.nolabel <- nzv-1

inTrain <- createDataPartition(y=train$label, p=0.7, list=F)

training <- train[inTrain, ]
CV <- train[-inTrain, ]

X <- as.matrix(training[, -1])
N <- nrow(X)
y <- training[, 1]

K <- length(unique(y))
X.proc <- X[, -nzv.nolabel]/max(X)
D <- ncol(X.proc)

Xcv <- as.matrix(CV[, -1])
ycv <- CV[, 1]
Xcv.proc <- Xcv[, -nzv.nolabel]/max(X)

Y <- matrix(0, N, K)
```

So, to get rid of the `nearZeroVar` function, I have tried to use the `Filter` function and the following `foo` function:

```
foo <- function(data) {
out <- lapply(data, function(x) length(unique(x)))
want <- which(!out > 1)
unlist(want)
}

nzv <- foo(trainingSet)
nzv.nolabel <- nzv - 1
```

But I get error messages: "Error in X[, training.nolabel]: incorrect number of dimensions. Execution halted" or something like "Non-conformable arrays". Any ideas on how to work around the `nearZeroVar" are strongly appreciated. Please, let me know if I should share some more details.

Answer (score 0):

It's not evident from the code posted that how `Filter()` was being used. 
Try the following;

```
# create sample data
R> df <- data.frame(a=1:10, b=sample(10:19), c=rep(5,10))
R> df
    a  b c
1   1 16 5
2   2 17 5
3   3 18 5
4   4 13 5
5   5 15 5
6   6 14 5
7   7 11 5
8   8 12 5
9   9 19 5
10 10 10 5
```

creating a custom function like;

```
R> zeroVarianceCol<- function(df){
  new_df<-Filter(var,df)
  }
```

passing the dataframe to this custom function like, `x<- zeroVarianceCol(df)` will remove the near zero variance column, in this case column c.

```
R> x
    a  b
1   1 16
2   2 17
3   3 18
4   4 13
5   5 15
6   6 14
7   7 11
8   8 12
9   9 19
10 10 10
```